# Negative binomial one-sided confidence interval?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, inference

Suppose someone was flipping a coin, and want to test the hypotheses:

$$
H_0: p=0.5 \\
H_a: p>0.5
$$

First, assume they decided to run 20 trials. They observed 14 heads and 6 tails. We can create a one-sided 95% CI in R using

```
binom.test(x = 14, n=20, p=0.5, alternative = "greater", conf.level = 0.95)
```

which returns a CI of (0.4921816, 1.0).

Now, assume instead that instead of fixing the 20 trials, the person flipped until they saw 6 tails. The data is the same, but now the data under the null is assumed to be distributed NegativeBinomial(6, 0.5) instead of Binomial(20,0.5).

How can I create a one-sided 95% CI using R, similar to that of the binomial case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the probability of success (seeing tails) is 0.4758 and you flip the coin until you get 6 successes, there is only a 5% chance that this will occur on flip 20 or later. In the R function pnbinom, the first argument is the number of failures. The probability of 20 or more flips is the probability of 14 or more failures (1- the probability of 13 or fewer failures).

```
1-pnbinom(14-1,size=6,prob=0.4758)
```

Thus, the 95% upper confidence bound for the probability of tails is 0.4758.
The 95% lower confidence bound for the probability of heads is 1-0.4758=0.5242.

This below finds the 95% lower confidence bound (0.1475) and 95% upper confidence bound (0.4758) for the probability of success from an experiment where you flip the coin until observing 6 successes (tails) and that happens after the 14th failure (heads).

```
uniroot(function(y,alpha) 1-pnbinom(14-1,size=6,prob=y)-(1-alpha),c(0.001,0.999),alpha=0.05)$root
uniroot(function(y,alpha) 1-pnbinom(14-1,size=6,prob=y)-alpha,c(0.001,0.999),alpha=0.05)$root
```

The two-sided 95% CI for the probability of tails is found by replacing alpha=0.05 with alpha=0.025 in the above two lines. That 95% CI is (0.126, 0.512) which implies the two-sided 95% CI for the probability of heads is (0.488, 0.874).